# Using Algolia is it possible to search an index and simultaneously retrieve results from a different index using a matching field of original hits?

Tags: algolia

**Example use case:**

An app user should be able to search a by name using full text search but whatever hits there are from the search - instead of pulling all of these, use the documentId for each hit to find matches in a different index and instead return those as the results.

Is that possible using Algolia and Firestore?